# How to get Canoscan LiDe 25 to work with simple scan in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, scanner, sane

After upgrading to 13.10 my scanner stopped working. Simple scan can kind of detect my scanner, but fails to scan. It keeps trying, instead of just telling that "no scanner has been found".

I also tried Xsane, which told me "no scanner could be detected"

My scanner always worked fine on older Ubuntu releases and still does on a laptop that runs 13.04

simple scan and Xsane work when run as root. seems like a permissions problem.

When the scanner is plugged-in simple scan freezes when i try to shut it down. Even if run as root.

Comment: Try to run xsane as root?

Comment: same problem here!